# html file upload and action on single button

Tags: html

this is my html form:

```
<button name="upload_inventory" id="upload_inventory" class="btn btn-purple btn-labeled fa">Upload Inventory</button>
```

I want to use it for file open dialog instead of using

```
<input type="file" name="upload_inventory" id="upload_inventory" class="btn btn-purple btn-labeled fa">
```

How to do that?

If i use button tag, It look like this:

[image]

If i use input tag it look like this:

[image]

Also how to use submit from inside the button element?

Comment: let me know , are you ready with jQuery??

Comment: yeah. i am planning to use that file submission from button part using jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to keep a "input type file" and hide it before user

```
    <input id="hideupload" name="hideupload" 
    type="file"  onChange="doFileText()" style="display:none; "/>
    <button onClick="doFile()" name="upload_inventory" 
    id="upload_inventory" class="btn btn-purple btn-labeled fa">Upload` Inventory</button>
```

Now you have to trigger the file click event on you button click , so that file dialog will open.

```
<script>
function doFile()
{
var x=$('#hideupload');
x.trigger( 'click' );
}
</script>
```

**OR With Pure JS**

```
function doFile()
    {
    var x=document.getElementById('hideupload');
    x.click();
    }
```

**LIVE**  http://jsfiddle.net/mailmerohit5/m4cny75b/